# How do I enable ratings for blogs?

Tags: blog, social, rating

I'm trying to add the rating feature for blog posts.

Any solutions please?

Comment: Please indicate what approach(es) you've tried already, what issues you've had, etc.

Comment: rating is enabled for lists and library but under list Post for blog i cant find this feature

Answer (score 5):

You can use Rating feature for you post in blog. In order to do this, click **Manage Post** > **List Settings** > **Rating settings** and then choose **Yes** under **Allow items in this list to be rated?**

Comment: If this isn't showing in the UI then [make sure the Rating feature is activated](http://kroondyk.blogspot.com/2010/06/turn-on-ratings-feature-in-sharepoint.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have Tagging enabled for the page's document library, you should be able to use SharePoint Designer and add a the rating control to the page or its layout:

```
<SharePointPortalControls:AverageRatingFieldControl 
 FieldName="Rating_x0020__x0028_0_x002d_5_x0029_" runat="server"/>
```

Source: [Adding rating ability to a SharePoint 2010 publishing page layout](http://www.khamis.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the Rating Feature is activated on the site collection. To proceed, go to **Site Actions** > **Site Settings** > **Go to top level site settings** > **Site collection features** and activate the **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** feature. After that, the **Rating Settings** link will appear under the **General Settings** of all lists or libraries of that site collection.

Only if the above is not working should you try to use the PowerShell command as described in the following blog post [Turn on Ratings Feature in SharePoint 2010](http://kroondyk.blogspot.com/2010/06/turn-on-ratings-feature-in-sharepoint.html) .

Once the **Rating Settings** appear, you can start using the rating feature for your posts in your blog. The following Microsoft article is extremely easy to follow: [Enable users to rate content](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-users-to-rate-content-HA101791797.aspx)